# How do I call WebApi method with parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi method with 2 parameters as followed:

```
public IQueryable<Facilities> GetFacilityList(string baseCode, string scope)
{
    return Object;
}
```

In my Asp.Net MVC I have the following so far:

```
    public ActionResult FacilityGrid()
    {
        List<Facilities> query;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));




            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/facilities");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
             //   Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>()
            }

        }
```

}

How do I call the WebApi and pass in two parameters?

Comment: Add them to the query string?

Comment: try using api/facilities?baseCode=baseCodeInput&scope=scopeInput

Answer (score 0):

You could create the query string manually as suggested in the comment to your post of code or by using  a class like the UriBuilder. This method seemed produce the desired response.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> QuetionTwoApiCall()
    {
         var builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost/api/question2");
         builder.Port = 50742;
         var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
         query["basecode"] = "somebasecode";
         query["scope"] = "somescope";
         builder.Query = query.ToString();       
         string url = builder.ToString();
         using (var client = new HttpClient()) {

             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
             HttpResponseMessage  response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
             string donothing = "do nothing";
       }
         return RedirectToAction("QuestionTwo");
    }
}
```